# OpenCV 2.4.9 LNK1104: cannot open file 'cxcore.lib'

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compile this [Image Alignment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24809/Image-Alignment-Algorithms) Algorith for Image Registration using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 2.4.9 and keep getting this linker error

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cxcore.lib'
```

In my understanding the problems origin in one or all of these includes

```
#include <cv.h>         // Include header for computer-vision part of OpenCV.
#include <highgui.h>    // Include header for GUI part of OpenCV.
#include "auxfunc.h"    // Header for our warping functions.
```

I tried switching those includes with various other combinations of includes but keep getting the above and other errors.  opencv works fine otherwise. I know the code is deprecated, but it should still work. Since I am quite new to c++ and opencv, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

These are my included libs in D:\lib\opencv-2.4.9\build\install\x86\vc11\lib. Since cxcore.lib is not among them, I tried changing the includes, which did not help.
opencv_calib3d249d.lib, opencv_contrib249d.lib, opencv_core249d.lib, opencv_features2d249d.lib, opencv_flann249d.lib, opencv_gpu249d.lib, opencv_highgui249d.lib, opencv_imgproc249d.lib, opencv_legacy249d.lib, opencv_ml249d.lib, opencv_nonfree249d.lib, opencv_objdetect249d.lib, opencv_photo249d.lib, opencv_stitching249d.lib, opencv_superres249d.lib, opencv_ts249d.lib, opencv_video249d.lib, opencv_videostab249d.lib

Comment: you probably should not try too hard *at all* with that. the code is from 2008, opencv's api and structure changed significantly.

Comment: did you search your harddisk and know where cxcore.lib is placed? enter that path to your project settings somewhere like "linker->additional library locations"

Comment: I searched my harddisk before I changed the includes. since only cxcore.hpp and cxcore.h exist, I tried changing the includes, which did not work.

Comment: When you installed OpenCV, cxcore.lib would've been placed in your install directory, with header files in <install_dir>/include and library files in <install_dir>/lib. If they're missing, then the installation may not have completed correctly.
Once you find the libraries, or reinstall if that's the case, then add the path to the libraries in Project->Properties->Configuration->Linker->General->AdditionalLibraryDirectories, and add the library names in Project->Properties->Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies.

Comment: The installation worked fine and did not have any errors. I figured, that maybe cxcore.lib was not part of the installation any more and was replaced by opencv_core249d.lib?

Comment: berak, I would like not using the code, but it seems to be the only code concerning registration in opencv using template matching. My images change brightness intensity drastically, template matching is the only method which seems to be working for me. But I also need to rotate, warp,scale etc. my images, and this code is all I found

Comment: cxcore.lib was removed in OpenCV 2.2. So you may need to download old OpenCV 2.1 or 2.0 to build your code.

Comment: ah, okay, as I feared. Thanks, but this is no option. I guess I'll have to live without it

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem (answered by Andrey Kamaev): cxcore.lib was removed in OpenCV 2.2. So you may need to download old OpenCV 2.1 or 2.0 to build your code.